# SwiftUI: adding hover effect to image link forces double tap to activate link

Tags: swiftui

I use the following code to create a Link with only an image (no text) and to add a hoverEffect:

```
Link(destination: URL(string: webURL)!, label: {
   Image("Home", bundle: Bundle.module)
            .resizable()
            .renderingMode(.template)
            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .padding(6)
            .contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5, style: .continuous))
            .hoverEffect(.highlight)
})
```

The hoverEffect causes the link to ignore the first tap. The user must double tap to activate the link. Has any one else sen this behavior and if so, what do I need to do to activate the link on the first tap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: If I move the last 3 lines out of the Image and onto the Link, all works well.